# How does .send() find connected receivers? Django

Tags: python, django, signals

I have been learning about signals, and am now trying to understand the basic, inner mechanics of how a signal is sent - and received. This post concerns the provided signal-objects(pre_save, post_save...etc), not writing custom ones.

Looking within the Django code for the model class, .send() is called on the imported signal 'pre_save'. When reading about .send() within the Signal class (found in dispatcher.py), there is a comment that says:

> ''Send signal from sender to all connected receivers.''

How exactly does .send() go about finding connected receivers? I have read that .connect() ensures that signals are connected to receivers, through 'signal dispatchers', which are instances of the Signal class.

Could a basic explanation be that the connect-method, found in the Signal class, takes the receiver name that is given to it as a parameter - and appends it to the specified list 'self.receivers'? And that that list is later checked to for possible receivers within the .send() method? Because that is the way it appears to me from reading the code.

It also seems, if my beginners-eyes have been able to read everything correctly, that an empty list is returned by the .send() method if no receivers are found. Is this true? Then why do I keep reading everywhere online that 'signals are always emitted' when in fact, they do not seem to be? Maybe that is just up to semantics, if returning an empty list is really emitting a signal...?

Could someone please help me connect the dots? Is my understanding, in basic terminology, correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking here. The signal *is* always emitted, even if nothing is listening to it. And `send` returns a list of the results of each of the connected receivers; if nothing is connected, then that list will be empty, yes.

Comment: Alright, thank you! To answer your question: I have understood that .send() is the method that emits the signals. Is my 'basic explanation' correct in that the .send() 'hooks' to receivers through them being added in the self.receivers list?